# How can I convert a number from base 8 to base 10?

Tags: math, radix

I know 75(base8) = 61(base10), but I can't easily find the formula for this. How does one convert from base 8 to base 10?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#Octal_to_Decimal_conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert any base to base 10 just do the following:

For every digit in the different base multiply that by the base and digit.  For example:

```
75 (base 8) = 7*8^1 + 5*8^0 = 61
```

Works for any base ... binary, hex, you name it just do that and it will convert to base 10.

Comment: so `5*8^0` is the same as `5*1`?

Comment: yes it is ... anything raised tot he zero power is equal to 1 ... aka 8^0 = 1

Comment: That's not a method for converting it to base 10, that's just a method for interpreting it as an integer. The base 10 conversion is done by your calculator (or else you just you did it subconsciously in your head).

Comment: @Mark: What's the difference? Once you get the integer 61, expressing it in base 10 is as easy as writing "61".

Answer (score 7):

0 * **8<sup>5</sup>** + 0 * **8<sup>4</sup>** + 0 * **8<sup>3</sup>** + 0 * **8<sup>2</sup>** + 7 * **8<sup>1</sup>** + 5 * **8<sup>0</sup>** = 61

Answer (score 2):

The formula is 1<sub>8</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub> and 10<sub>8</sub> = 8<sub>10</sub>.  Everything else can be derived from that.

If you have a sequence of base 8 digits you want to convert to a base 10 number, process them from left to right, keeping a total you initialize at zero.  For each digit x, set the total to 8*total+x.  After processing the last digit, the total will be the base ten value of the base 8 sequence.

Answer (score 1):

75 in base 8 = 5*8^0 + 7*8^1 = 5 + 56 = 61

In general, to convert the number a_1a_2a_3...a_n from base k to base 10, use the formula:

a_n*k^0 + a_(n-1)*k^1 + ... + a_1*k^(n-1).

Answer (score 0):

137461(base8) =
1 x 8^0 +
6 x 8^1 +
4 x 8^2 +
7 x 8^3 +
3 x 8^4 +
1 x 8^5

Answer (score 0):

given this is a programming site:

```
int oct_to_dec = 075;
printf("%d",oct_to_dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Integers, from base 8 to base 10,
say, you have 144 in base 8, then to convert it to base 10,

multiply the right most/least-significant digit by 8 raised to 0 that is 1
So, 1 x 4 = 4
now move towards left and multiply the digit on immediate left by 8 raised to 1(8),
So, 8 x 4 = 32
again, move towards left and multiply the digit on immediate left by 8 raised to 2(64),
So, 64 x 1 = 64

Now, add all these = 64 + 32 + 4 = 100.

So 144 in base 8 is 100 in base 10.

Had there been more digits towards the left, we would have followed the same pattern and later add them to get our answer. Hope it helped.